# "Parent Key Not Found" although it exists (within the TX)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, view, foreign-keys

I just observed a strange behaviour (of course Oracle is probably supposed to behave this way, but it didn't fit in my world view yet):

I try to insert two rows into a parent and a child table, both within the same transaction:

```
INSERT INTO V_Parent (ID, Name) VALUES (777, 'Hello World');
INSERT INTO T_Child (ParentID, Name) VALUES (777, 'Foo Bar');
```

The Child table has a `(ParentID) references Parent.ID`  foreign key constraint.

On the second statement Oracle fails with the error message **"Parent key not found."**

If I disable the FK constraint, it works. I have asserted that the ParentID and the Parent.ID match, and I am 100% sure that the first line is executed successfully before the second one. Further, I have tried to commit each statement, which worked fine.

**However,** as the prefixes in my code example suggest, the first **INSERT is actually done on a view** of the parent table. The reason is that I use NHibernate and the mapping uses the view in background (which didn't cause any problems until today).

**Q1: Could it be that inserting on a view is deferred by Oracle so that the second statement fails?**

**Q2: How can I remedy this problem best?**

- Do I need to define INSTEAD OF triggers on the views?
- Can I change a setting on the VIEW definition?
- Can I change a setting on the FOREIGN KEY definition?
- (I *must not* bend the hibernate mapping to the original table: It's a demand to use the views so changes and/or security issues can be hidden behind the views)

*Details: C# WinForms Application - NHibernate - Oracle 10.2* - T_Child: *Sooner or later I will use a view for that table, too, it's simply not defined yet.*

---

**Edit**: More Details according to the comments:

- The **ID is assigned by NHibernate** using an Oracle sequence (`<generator class="sequence">`), and is part of the INSERT statement as in my example. I also verified that the resulting ID in the table row matches the one NHibernate saved in the mapped object.
- **The view** is defined as a SELECT that **JOINS some fields** of other tables. However, on insert/update I only change the fields belonging to the main table ("T_PARENT"), and that normally works fine.
- The current **foreign key** constraint is **not deferrable**, but that shouldn't have any effect because the parent statement is executed before the child statement. *)

*) Hmm... let me think: Since I use an NHibernate session for submitting the SQL queries, **could it be that NHibernate executes them in a different order than I told it to?**

<strike>I'll investigate on that.</strike> => It seems so, see my own answer.

This is how the actual code looks like:

```
ISession session = this.DAOFactory.NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    // parent.ID == 0
    session.SaveOrUpdate(parent);
    // parent.ID == 777 (for example)

    ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(
        "INSERT INTO T_CHILD (PARENT_ID, NAME) VALUES (:parentId, :name)");
    query.SetDecimal("parentId", parent.ID);
    query.SetDecimal("name", "Foo Bar");

    query.ExecuteUpdate(); // Fails with ORA-Exception

    tx.Commit();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    tx.Rollback();
    throw;
}
finally
{
    session.Close();
}
```

Comment: May be insert firstly done for child table? Can you check this? also Look to deferrable constraints (SET CONSTRAINT ...) it is allow you insert data in any order and validate data only at end of transaction

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg05itg.htm#7185

Comment: What is the definition of the view?  Does it already have an INSTEAD OF trigger?

Comment: Maybe there is a trigger that replaces your ID of 777 with a freshly generated number from a Sequence?

Comment: Hi all, the ID is generated by NHibernate from an oracle sequence (`<generator class="sequence">`) and is included in the INSERT statement. The database does not change the ID (I verified that the ID I could find in the DB afterwards matched the one found in the mapped object.

Comment: There are no triggers in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it.

As stated in the update to my question, it seems that the NHibernate session mixes the order of the SQL statements. To remedy this, I added the following line of code:

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(parent);
session.Flush();
// (...)
query.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define an INSTEAD OF trigger if the view is [already updateable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#sthref1187). Inserting in a view that has a simple relation with its base table will behave as inserting in the base table -- consider:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER);

Table created

SQL> CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT a, b FROM t;

View created

SQL> INSERT INTO v VALUES (1,2);

1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2
```

For your insert problem, you probably have a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the base table (with the `id` colomn filled by a sequence).

Comment: Hi Vincent, I don't. The ID is generated by NHibernate using an Oracle Sequence (<generator class="sequence">), and is passed to the INSERT statement. The view is indeed updatable, the statements do insert the data, which I verified by committing each statement individually. Only if I don't commit in between, it won't work.